# why can't I initialise this set

Tags: swift

```
var startset=Set<String>("asdasd","sadad")
```

**Error :**

Missing argument label 'arrayLiteral:' in call

---

I am inspired by this:

```
var ok=String("sdsf")
```

prints  sdsf

Comment: another way would be `var startSet: Set<String> = ["test", "testing"]`

Comment: my question is why we cannot do in that way i said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `String` because it just so happens that `String` has an initialiser:

```
public init<S>(_ other: S) where S : LosslessStringConvertible, S : Sequence, S.Element == Character
```

`String` fits all the constrains of `S`, so it can be passed to this initialiser, and you are able to create a string this way.

`Set` is a totally different class, and it doesn't have any initialiser to which you can pass 2 `String`s, so you can't create a set by passing 2 strings.

If you want to create a set with 2 strings as its elements, you can use an array literal:

```
let set: Set<String> = ["asdasd","sadad"]
```

Alternatively, if you want to call an initialiser explicitly,

```
let set = Set<String>(["asdasd","sadad"])
```

Answer (score 1):

To initialize a `Set` you need values in type of an Sequence: for example an Array.

To do this:

```
var startset=Set<String>(["asdasd","sadad"])
```